# CMake Eorror When Building Simulink DDS Blockset Example Model shapesdemo

Tags: cmake, build, code-generation, simulink, data-distribution-service

I want to build the Simulink Model *shapesdemo* which is incorporated in **DDS(Data Distribution Service) Blockset** Examples. I follow the guidance illustrated in *shapesdemo.mlx* file. In the last step when I try to generate the code and build model, the Simulink *Diagnostic Viewer* shows the following errors:

---

> **Validation errors:**
> Caused by:
> %TempDir%\tp998d3b00_e80a_4d1e_8098_41b99085af41>set CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=TRUE
>  
> %TempDir%\tp998d3b00_e80a_4d1e_8098_41b99085af41>D:\MATLAB\R2023b\bin\win64\cmake\bin\cmake.exe -S . -B .  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=".."
> -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also "%TempDir%/tp998d3b00_e80a_4d1e_8098_41b99085af41/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>  
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
>  Running
>  
>  'nmake' '-?'
>  
>  failed with:
>   **System Cannot Find Specified File**
>  
>  
> CMake Error:CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
> CMake Error:CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
> The cmake command returned an error of 1

Based on the error messages, I find that there is no *tp998d3b00_e80a_4d1e_8098_41b99085af41* folder in the temporary directory **%TempDir%**. I have check that the **MW_MINGW64_LOC** environment variable is set correctly, whose value is **C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2023b\3P.instrset\mingw_w64.instrset**.
I want to know where is the *CMakeLists.txt* file as mentioned in the error messages.

Comment: You need to install `nmake` utility. Or specify other [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html), for which you have a built tool.